# Make generated Swift (or Swift doc) file which will have list of all UIViewControllers subclasses

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, shell, scripting

I want to have a file that will be generated at each build. (It looks like I need to build a phase script). This file should have a list of all files which have names like [ANY]ViewController patterns. It can be any format of file (txt, .swift,.md).[image]
Can you please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Your question is taggued with ruby & shell. But you can also build a script in Swift. Which language do you prefer? What have you tried? Also, can you have two `UIViewController` subclass defined in a single file? Can a `UIViewController` class have a different name than the file?

Comment: For example: shell, 1 controller per file, all controllers have [ANY]UIViewController name pattern. I did not try anything till now. (I did not know what the difference between different languages (and which are allowed and not allowed for tasks like these)

Comment: Something like `find ./ -name '*ViewController*' -execdir basename {} .swift ';' | sort` might be a good start. Look for bash, each step. You can test it in `Terminal.app`...